# Makefile automatic variable changed by prerequisite

Tags: makefile, prerequisites

first time here. I am relatively new to makefiles. Here is my current makefile:

```
    # Closure compiler php script path
    closure = ../../cli/scripts/Compilers/closure.php

    # Destination directory
    dest = ../../static/js/

    # Build directory
    build = build/

    # Tell "make" to search build and destination dirs
    vpath %.o $(build)
    vpath %.js $(dest)

    all: main.js
        @echo "Done.";

    main.js: \
            date.o \
            jquery.autocomplete.o \
            jquery.bullseye.o \
            jquery.clickopen.o \
            jquery.fbmodal.o \
            jquery.helpers.o \
            jquery.pulljson.o \
            jquery.thumbrotate.o \
            jquery.timefmt.o \
            jquery.tools.o \
            layout.main.o
        cat  $^ > $(dest)$@

    %.o: %.js
        php  $(closure)  $*.js  $(build)$@

    clean:
        rm -rf  $(build)*.o
        rm -rf  $(dest)*.js
```

The problem is with the following line:
`cat  $^ > $(dest)$@`.

It is supposed to cat all the prerequisite objects (minified javascript) into one final js library. According to makefile docs, `$^` is an automatic variable which contains a list of prerequisites with directories they are in. From my experience, it behaves differently depending on wether prerequisite needs to be compiled or not.

If prerequisite is up-to-date, this code works perfectly and `$^` contains a list like:

```
build/date.o build/jquery.autocomplete.o build/jquery.bullseye.o....
```

However if prerequisite needs a fresh compile, then `$^` gets directory part stripped and looks like:

```
date.o jquery.autocomplete.o jquery.bullseye.o
```

Only the file which needs a fresh compile gets directory part stripped.

I have managed to work around this issue by replacing

`cat  $^ > $(dest)$@`

with

`cat  $(addprefix $(build), $(^F) ) > $(dest)$@`.

I don't like it because:

1. It's a hack
2. `$(^F)` is semi-deprecated
3. I want to understand why make behaves like this.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

```
# Tell "make" to search build and destination dirs
vpath %.o $(build)
```

If Make is looking for `foo.o`, it will look in the local directory first. If it finds no `foo.o` there, it will look in `$(build)` (i.e. `build/`, and you might reconsider your variable names).

And how would Make build `foo.o`, if it couldn't find it anywhere? With this rule:

```
%.o: %.js
    php  $(closure)  $*.js  $(build)$@
```

This rule violates an important guideline of makefiles, in that the target (`foo.o`) is not the name of the thing actually built (`build/foo.o`).

Now consider what happens when Make tries to execute this rule:

```
main.js: date.o ...
    cat  $^ > $(dest)$@
```

So if `date.o` is up to date, it's in `build/`. Make finds it there, and the automatic variable `$^` expands to `build/date.o ...`

But if `date.o` must be rebuilt, then Make looks to the `%.o` rule, which promises to build `date.o` (*not* `build/date.o`), so Make takes that rule at its word and `$^` expands to `date.o ...`

There are several ways to solve this problem. I'd do something like this:

```
OBJS := date.o jquery.autocomplete.o jquery.bullseye.o ...
OBJS := $(addprefix $(build),$(OBJS))

$(dest)main.js: $(OBJS)
    cat  $^ > $@

# you might have to tinker with this rule a little
$(build)%.o: %.js
    php  $(closure)  $<  $@
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to tell make within the `%.o: %.js` rule that the generated file is actually in another location than the main dir?

Comment: @Karolis: You should not tell make that, you should change the rule to actually build the stated target, otherwise make can't deduce when it has to execute the rule.